# Replace object with another in the entire process / become in Python

Tags: python, reference

**Context:**
I want to replace an object with another:

```
x = []
r = [2]
replace(x, r)
assert x == [2]
assert x is r
```

In Smalltalk this would be called `become` .

**Question:**
How would I do that? Would I need to create a C-extension or is there already something like this?

**I tried:** [This](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/74ae8e03a55a6a3ea533) But I need to handle so many cases. Just changing the object behind the pointer would be enough for me.

**Reason:** I want to implement extensions like features, refinements and subjects. Sometimes I can not change the class of an builtin object `os.__class__ = X` to enable more flexibility. Since I can not do that, I though about replacing.

**Concrete Example of Usage:**

A subjective view:

```
import pylung
pylung.deutsch()

import os # I want to preserve object identity with the original os

os.ERREICHE_SETZEN
os.durchlaufe(...)
```

A translation:

```
import os
import pylung

os = pylung.translate(os, 'deutsch') # German

@os.walk
def durchlaufe(ordner, oben_nach_unten, folge_links):
    """Ordner baum erzeuger
"""
```

Comment: What are those languages that have this `become`??

Comment: You might be able to do this in a C extension, but then you're really messing with the language core and changing it.  That's really dicey.  Can you provide the reasoning behind why you want to do this?  Maybe we can provide some insight into a better way

Comment: Can you explain what that would be useful for? If you do `x = r`, both names already point to the same (mutable) object, so changes to that object would impact both `x` and `r`...

Comment: You can't monkeypatch builtin types. Either subclass them, or learn Ruby.

Comment: Don't learn Ruby. Just subclass.

Comment: Ok subclass, and replace them? I would like to create a new module os for example that is in German. Perserving object identity with what is in os.

Comment: Oh for the love of Bill Gates, please don't create another Germanified programming language. Excel macros were bad enough.

Comment: @kirelagin: Point taken. I admit I had it coming :)

Comment: @Tim Pitzcker It is about the flexibility to choose ones language to get an entrance, to enable more subjectivity in your progam, to write and think in ones own words without forcing others to adapt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to do this...

```
import pylung
pylung.deutsch()

import os # I want to preserve object identity with the original os

os.ERREICHE_SETZEN
os.durchlaufe(...)
```

...and retain compatibility with existing libraries (which will use the English names), it's probably easiest to add additional attributes to the `os` module, rather than replacing them. For example...

```
# pylung.py
def deutsch():
    import os
    os.durchlaufe = os.walk
    # etc...
```

...if you also want to translate module names, say `collections` to `kollektionen`, you can do something like this...

```
# pylung.py
import sys

def deutsch():
    import os
    os.durchlaufe = os.walk
    # etc...
    import collections
    sys.modules['kollektionen'] = sys.modules['collections']
```

...again, ensuring you keep the original module name in place for compatibility.

You could also look at using a [custom import hook](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) to do the module translations on-demand, so you need only replace the symbols that are actually used in the script.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `=` does what you want:

```
x = []
r = [2]
x = r
assert x == [2]
assert x == r
assert x is r
```

Comment: And all this time, my mind was stuck in the "use a function" box.  +1

Comment: ...and now the OP has written what he *actually* wants to do - which unfortunately is something entirely different from what he wrote in the question before...

Comment: @User Only if you delete your question an create a new one with the correct question.;)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the only way to do this natively is through assignment:

```
x = []
r = [2]
x = r
assert x == [2]
assert x is r
```

However, this is so trivial I doubt it is what you're looking for. More likely you want *all* references to `r` to be updated. This isn't possible with Python.  You can do it, after a fashion, with slice assignment, but this won't actually change the object identity, so your last `assert` will fail, and also this only works with certain types such as lists (though some other container types have similar capabilities; for example with a `dict` you could `.clear()` then `.update()`).

```
x = []
r = [2]
x[:] = r
assert x == [2]
assert x is r     # fails
```

The closest you can come, probably, is with a wrapper object that holds the list as an attribute. If the wrapper is always passed around, never the list, and the list is always accessed *through* the wrapper, then you can simply update the attribute and every other reference will see it.

Edit: Looking at your specific use case, which you added after I wrote the above, it doesn't actually require replacing anything. You can just set the translated function/class names onto the existing module object (removing the existing ones, if that's necessary). An easier way would probably to make an entirely new module and stick it into `sys.modules[modulename]`. As long as you do this before any other modules import it, they will never see the untranslated module.

Of course, this is a silly thing to do; there is no good way to machine-translate Python code into another human language. Translate it by hand and provide it to interested parties as an importable module of its own.

Answer (score 1):

You should realise that a variable is actually nothing more than a name that is being searched in dictionaries representing scopes.

Scopes (dictionaries) actually contain references (think, pointers). You can replace a pointer, but in Python there is no way to change an object in-place. That's what you can do with references in C (which give you access to the underlying memory cell), but there is a limitation that objects sizes must match. So, no, you can't.

Comment: +1 "objects sizes must match" - then it can be made possible.